# How to mock and test redux-thunk actions?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I can't find a way how to properly test async redux actions that are using **other** actions inside it's body:

```
import {postRequest} from './http'

export function saveAnswer (id, answer) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: SAVE_ANSWER})

    return dispatch(postRequest(ANSWERS_ENDPOINT, {id, answer}))
  }
}
```

I want to stub `postRequest` so that it's logic is not executed.

I have setup for spec:

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import * as ACTIONS from '../answers'
import * as HTTP_ACTIONS from '../http'

const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk])
const store = mockStore({})


describe('saveAnswer()', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    sinon.stub(HTTP_ACTIONS, 'postRequest').returns(Promise.resolve({}))

    store.dispatch(ACTIONS.saveAnswer(ID, ANSWER))
  })
})
```

When I run spec I get this error:
`Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

I don't understand what am I doing wrong but it has to do something with stubbing `postRequest` action.

How can I properly stub that action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `redux-thunk` argument of `dispatch` must be a function or plain object. In your case `postRequest` returns Promise object which is not plain object (nor function;). As a result you call `dispatch` with promise object as argument. So please make sure that you call `dispatch` with argument which is either function or plain action object (with `type` property).

You can rewrite your code like this (assuming that `postRequest` returns promise) and then error should disappear:

```
import {postRequest} from './http'

export function saveAnswer (id, answer) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: SAVE_ANSWER})
    postRequest(ANSWERS_ENDPOINT, {id, answer})
      .then((response) => dispatch({
         type: ANSWER_SAVED,
         data: response
      }));
  };
}
```

**Answer update after comment:**

So since `postRequest` doesn't return Promise object but function the problem is in how you're stubbing it. Please try this (stub should also return function instead of Promise object):

```
const mockFuntion = () => Promise.resolve({}); // here can also  be an spy function if needed
sinon.stub(HTTP_ACTIONS, 'postRequest').returns(mockFuntion);
```

Comment: I can't do that because `postRequest` internally uses `dispatch` as well:
export function postRequest (url, body) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: POST_REQUEST, url, body})
  }
}

Comment: thanks, this is actually what was missing and this is what came to my mind yesterday just before going to sleep! :D
Could you also please edit your answer and add this as a full solution (see that I need to return promise): sinon.stub(HTTP_ACTIONS, 'postRequest').returns(() => Promise.resolve({}))